# Blender imports SVG only "outlined" (Fillings are vanished)

Tags: import, svg

If I import SVG files to my Blender-Project, then the SVG objects are only displayed "outlined", without surfaces (but these surfaces were definitely there in Inkscape).

*Original in Inkscape:*

[image]

*After import into my project:*

[image]

But if I open Blender-default (without loading my project) and import the same SVG files - then they appear correctly, with surfaces or filled areas.

*After import into the Blender default-Scene:*

[image]

Only in my current project I can't import SVG without the surfaces of the SVG disappearing!

As you can see, however, the settings of the SVG curves (SVG to my project versus blender default) are the same.

[image]

So in the default setting of Blender imported SVG are filled - but if I import them in my project they are not.

What can this be and how can I fix it?

Best regards!

PS: It makes no difference which Blender version I use (I have tried 2.71 and 2.79b - with the same results)

Comment: You just seem to be in the wrong viewport shading mode. Press `Z`

Comment: It seems you are right!
Thank you very much!
In the german language there is a saying:
"Sometimes you do not see the forest through the trees". :o)

Comment: In the future please don't crop the images so tight, Not showing the interface makes it harder to guess what the problem is.